# How to make this jQuery event handler in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-plugins

I am creating a web application in Angular 2. On one of the pages, I use a jQuery plugin called [jquery-comments](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments), to enable user comments.

Now I'd like to show a custom dialog box, if the user clicks the jquery-comments "Reply" button.

[image]

If it was jQuery, I would do something like:

```
$('.jquery-comments .reply').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...here I can show my custom dialog box or something else        
});
```

But how would I make a similar event handler in Angular 2, without changing the jquery-comments plugin?

Answer (score 1):

> In your angular component you should reference a DOM element from the
>   template using @ViewChild() After the view has been initialized you
>   can use the nativeElement property of this object and pass to jQuery.
>
> Declaring $ (or jQuery) as JQueryStatic will give you a typed
>   reference to jQuery.

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/510788

You can catch the click after injecting jQuery into your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler click with Angular like so...

Some Component HTML

```
<div class="reply" (click)="showComments($event)"></div>
```

Passing $event will give you the same event object that you would get by just passing event with vanilla js.

Some Component

```
    class someComponent {

      constructor() {
    }

    showComments(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do the jquery stuff here.
    }

    }
```

Comment: No that won't work. As I wrote, I don't want to change the code of the jquery-comments plugin, which I would have to, if I were to add a (click) event handler as you suggest.

Comment: I don't think I am understanding what you mean by change the jquery plugin code.

Comment: The "Reply" button is part of the jquery-comment plugin. If I should do <div class="reply" (click)="showComments($event)"></div>, I would need to do this inside the plugin.