# How to import external dependencies in Typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, import

I want to import JQuery using Typescript and I do what the official tutorial of Typescript say:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Still, I get an error:

> "cannot find module jquery"

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2 that should h;elp

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Typescript typings for the library. Run `npm install -SD @types/jquery`