# Add CSS property in Angualr2 with MetaWidget

Tags: css, angular, metawidget

I am trying to add CSS when clicked on row or column of table, Following is code

```
private rowClicked(event: Event): void {
   event.srcElement.setAttribute("class", "highlighted");
}
```

But it's not working as accepted. Am I doing in wrong way, Is there any alternate way to add CSS dynamically?

### Note-

Is there any way to add CSS using dom element, my table has thousands of data and to create this table, I have used **[MetaWidget](http://metawidget.org/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to your problem is to assign a unique ID to each included element together with employing another variable to hold selected ID. The logic to turn on `my-class` CSS class will now be based on the selected ID.

Your new HTML template:

```
<div (click)="rowClicked(1);" [ngClass]="{'my-class': highlightedDiv === 1}">
  > I'm a div that gets styled on click
</div>
```

Your `rowClicked` function:

```
highlightedDiv: number;

rowClicked(newValue: number) {
  if (this.highlightedDiv === newValue) {
    this.highlightedDiv = 0;
  }
  else {
    this.highlightedDiv = newValue;
  }
}
```

A working demo is [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fNoXWhUhMaUoeMihbGYd?p=preview).

More can be found **[here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/)**.

---

You are using [MetaWidget](http://metawidget.org/), but you are not mentioning what version you are using.

If you want work with [Angular2](http://www.angular2.com/) and [MetaWidget](http://metawidget.org/), you should have use a compatible version of [MetaWidget](http://metawidget.org/), which can be found here-

https://github.com/AmitsBizruntime/MetawidetA2

Using this library will be the best solution for you.

### Re-

Angular does not work based on DOM, it works based on Component.
If you like to work on DOM, then you should include jQuery in tour angular project from here-

[How to use jQuery with Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2/30662773#30662773)

But it is not a good practice.

Comment: thanx for answer, Is there any way to add css using dom element, my table has thousands of data and these table I have created using metawidget which use javascript

Comment: Your question and my answer is updated, I think you have your answer now :)

Comment: @Abar Jahin, thank you, actually I am one of the contributor of Angular2-metawidget. :)