# Selecting template element and passing to jQuery in Angular 2 component

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to work out how to use jQuery with Angular 2.  I have been trying to follow the example below that mentions that Angular should control the DOM and I should pass the element to jQuery.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/657477

I think I am not understanding how the `@ViewChild()` works.

I have a div in my component template:

```
<div id="screenshot">
 // ... content here
</div>
```

So I declare jQuery as any:

```
declare var $:any;
```

add this property:

```
@ViewChild('screenshot') el:ElementRef;
```

And then to test things out just try to call hide on it in the ngAfterViewInit():

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).hide();
}
```

This throws the exception:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

So my view query is not finding the element?  I checked the docs for `@ViewChild` and it seems to take a nested component as parameter.  I think I am definitely doing somethign wrong here.

I want to be able to do various work with jQuery in the component so I need to be able to use a selector then call the jquery method.

Am I using the wrong approach?  How should I pass an element to jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small change needs to be made as shown below,

```
<div #screenshot>          //replaced id="screenshot" by #screenshot
   // ... content here
</div>

@ViewChild('screenshot') el:ElementRef;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like it's working now.  (I'll accept when countdown finished)

Comment: `<div #screenshot id="screenshot">` was needed otherwise the ID wasn't output as html.

Comment: saved my day :)