# Angularcli Jquery sideNav

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I am using `angular-cli` and `mdbootstrap`

The issue i have is trying to open the side nav `$(".button-collapse").sideNav('show');` just aint working.

I tried the following

1. Removed the `#` from the anchor tag
2. `declare var $:any` and added `$(".button-collapse").sideNav('show');` in a public function
3. added an external file in the scripts of the angular-cli json

Any other ideas?

Comment: post your html and where exactly you're calling `$(".button-collapse").sideNav('show')` in your angular code.

Comment: ideally, in your angular app, there is no need for jquery selectors

Comment: @Blauhirn everytime i work with a framework i think so too but seems like you cant get rid of jquery yet :)

Comment: i found a solution here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2`

Comment: Please some admin close this as a duplicate and apologies

Comment: @user3052526 flag the post if you think it's a duplicate

Comment: @AhmedMusallam yup