# How use jquery in template of Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

How use JQuery in template in component of Angular 2?

Example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'  
import * as $ from 'jquery';
...
```

in template of the component use

```
<p (click)="$('#myModal').modal('show');">show</p>
```

it return this error

ERROR TypeError: co.$ is not a function {}

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2

Answer (score 1):

Don't go through the angular framework if you do not need it.

```
<p onclick="$('#myModal').modal('show');">show</p>
```

By trying to use `(click)` the references are resolved based on the containing angular component so angular attempts to resolve `$` as an instance on that component.

Alternatively you have to create a method in your component that then calls through to jquery. This method is then called from the template using `(click)`.

Comment: Yes I need use angular 2

Comment: @alehn96 - not with the code above you don't. Nothing in `$('#myModal').modal('show')` uses anything specific to `angular2`.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to create method in component and when the event is  invoked, then use jquery, is only way?

Comment: @alehn96 - correct. Either: register to `onclick`. Use angular's `(click)` and have the `jquery` call inside the method in your component. Or create a new angular directive that registers to `click` and executes the jquery code.

Comment: How I use jquery in template of a component?

Comment: Thanks, I resolve with that 
$(this.elRef.nativeElement).find('#myModal').modal('show'); in the component where elRef:ElementRef

Answer (score 0):

Build a custom directive that will communicate with jquery.

```
@Directive({selector:'[trigger]'})
export class TriggerModelDirective {

  constructor(private el: elementRef) {
  }

  onInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener(()=> {
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
}
```

You might need to add removeEventListener and also wrap $ into opaque token for Angular.

Comment: Thanks, I resolve with that $(this.elRef.nativeElement).find('#myModal').modal('show'); in the component where elRef:ElementRef