# Angular2 : Using Jquery in Angular2 : Error: No provider for Token jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to use Jquery in my Angular2 application. I did the following:

- I installed using npm `package.json`

  ```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery":"2.0.42"
  }
  ```
- I created a `jQuery.service.ts` file and declared an `OpaqueToken` to expose this library

  ```
  import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'

  export let JQ_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('jQuery');
  ```
- I imported and declared the `jQuery` token in `app.module.ts`

  ```
  import {JQ_TOKEN} from './common/jQueryService'
  declare let jQuery : Object;
  ```

Now I am trying to access the $ of `jQuery` in my `component.ts` file

```
import {JQ_TOKEN} from './jQueryService'

export class simpleModal {
  @ViewChild('sessionModal') contentEl : ElementRef;

  constructor(private elRef : ElementRef, @Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $ : any){}

  closeModal() {
    this.$(this.contentEl.nativeElement).modal('hide');
  }
}
```

And I get the following error:

> Error: No provider for Token jQuery!

Can someone please guide me on why this error appears?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

Comment: The link that you mentioned does not implement exposing jQuery with Opaque Tokens. I want to expose my third party service with Opaque Tokens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please include jquery file in your index.html and

declare jQuery like this declare var jQuery:any; in your component and you can use 
it no need to include extra things.

Comment: although this works, it makes your code very hard to test because you're not relying on a global instead of an injected service.