# air-datepicker not work in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

With static html it easy to use (http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="dist/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="dist/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Include English language -->
        <script src="dist/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

But I don`t know how to use it with angular 4.

Install air-datepicker with

```
npm i air-datepicker --save
```

In component write

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
import 'air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js';
```

But input not use it

```
<input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-position="right top" />
```

If add this js file to ".angular-cli.json" It not work

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to import js files to components. Steps for add air-picker or other jquery plugin to your project

1. Install npm dependencies

   ```
   npm install jquery air-datepicker --save
   ```
2. Let know to webpack what js and css should be added to bundle (.angular-cli file)

   ```
     "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js",
       "../node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"
     ]

     "styles": [
       "styles.scss",
       "../node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/css/datepicker.min.css"
     ]
   ```
3. In component method `ngAfterViewInit()` initialize the plugin
   `($('#datepicker') as any).datepicker();`

Seems you cannot initialize plugin with class `datepicker-here`, you should use manual initialization.

How to use jquery with angular 2 you could see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/5801305)

If it`s not clear, you could contact me