# Angular 4 jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to use jquery to my Angular 4 app.I had followed all the steps to install jquery on my Angular 4.However jquery still dont work.
I had put the jquery code on the component like this.

home.component.ts

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery'
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService,public 
afAuth: AngularFireAuth,) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showAppinfo").click(function(){
      $("#appinfo").slideToggle();
  });
});
ngOnInit()
{}
}
```

And my Html is the following
home.component.html

```
    <h1>This is Home page!!</h1>
    <h2 id="showAppinfo">Basic App-info</h2>
    <ul class="list-group" id="appinfo">
      <li class="list-group-item">Publiser: {{ (appinfo | async)?.Publisher }}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Publication_Year: {{ (appinfo | async)?.Publication_Year }}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Version: {{ (appinfo | async)?.Version }}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Registered Users: {{ (appinfo | async)?.Rusers }}</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Languages: {{ (appinfo | async)?.Language }}(Only)</li>
   </ul>
```

But nothing happens when I click on `<h2 id="showAppinfo">Basic App-info</h2>`. Can you tell my if I am using the jquery code in the correct place?? The problem is on code or on the jquery instalation??

Comment: are you using angular-cli? and you should have `import * as $ from 'jquery'` if you want to use it as usual

Comment: did you set jquery on angular-cli.json ?

Comment: I found a link which explained how to install jquery on angular 4 I did all the steps.So the code is fine and the problem is in installation??

Comment: Yes i am using angular-cli I changed my import to `import * as $ from 'jquery' `  all I had set  jquery on angular-cli.json but still dont work..

Comment: I assume that your `angular-cli.json` has a correct path to the jquery* library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you're trying to manipulate your template in the constructor. But when your component constructor executes, `#showAppinfo` and `#appInfo` elements don't exist yet because the view has not been built.

Operations that depend on view elements need to be performed at the earliest in the [`ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnAfterViewInit 
...

ngAfterViewInit(){
  // do your template manipulation here
}
```

You can test this with something like `console.log($("#showAppinfo"))` and you'll see that it doesn't log any element `constructor()`, but it does in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: My friend uoooww resolve my problem thak you very much

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps that works for me:

Install jquery
npm install jquery

Install ts type
npm install @types/jquery

Add jquery.min.js in your .angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Create a service to JQuery with the Token, Provider and Factory:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export const JQUERY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<JQueryStatic>('jquery');

export function jQueryFactory() {
    return $;
}

export const JQUERY_PROVIDER = { provide: JQUERY_TOKEN, useFactory: jQueryFactory };
```

Add the Provider in Module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    JQUERY_PROVIDER,
    ...
  ]
})
```

Use DI in any component:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(JQUERY_TOKEN) private $: JQueryStatic
  )
```

Be happy :D

```
this.$('body').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Easiest and Shortest way possible to use jQuery in Angular 2/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093807/easiest-and-shortest-way-possible-to-use-jquery-in-angular-2-4)

**1st Step**

From index.html

> ***my-test-project\src\index.html***

Type jQuery cdn below `app-root` tag.

```
...
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

**2nd Step**

> ***my-test-project\src\app\test\test.component.ts***

Go to your desired components .ts script.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// this line will allow you to use jQuery
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
```

**3rd Step**

> ***my-test-project\src\app\test\test.component.ts***

Test jQuery by logging `'I<3Cats'` inside jQuery syntax `$(() => { /* content here */ })`.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(() => {
      console.log('hello there!');
    });
  }

}
```

You can also use this technique with other javscript libraries. I don't know if this is safe but will sure help you. quite

Answer (score 1):

i had an issue with jquery not working on bootstrap navbar and solved like this...

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
//declare var $: any; //old code..

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.navbar-nav>li>a').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.navbar-toggler').classList.toggle('collapsed');
        this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.navbar-collapse').classList.toggle('show');
      });
    })

    //old code...
    // $('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function () {
    //   $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    // });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what slideToggle() is doing, but FYI in Angular if you added
 #ref to h2..
you can then add

```
@ViewChild('ref')
h2El:Element;
```

in Typescript associated to the HTML.
to do equivalent of $("#showAppinfo")..

If you used this in the HTML

```
<h2 #ref (click)="handler()">...</h2>
```

you'd have click handler..
so in Typescript add

```
handler() {
 this.h2El.slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, slideToogle() is a jquery function I tried to do the way you said but I get error on `this.h2El.slideToggle();` it Says `[ts] Property 'slideToggle' does not exist on type 'Element'..` seems like i can't use jquery on elements like this..

Comment: @Zekelonas I think `$(event.target).slideToggle();` would be more appropriate. But if you can't use Jquery at all, then this doesn't matter...

Comment: Element is an Interface. There are interfaces with varying levels of specificity.
There is a more complete list here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API
For example, HTMLDivElement.
In Typescript you can cast variables with either of these syntaxes:
elDiv as HTMLDivElement or <HTMLDivElement>elDiv
Sometimes that gives you the ability to call a method.
But I suspect JQuery is embellishing the underlying interface prototypes to add slideToggle().
So you will probably still need jQuery at some point in your code.

Answer (score 0):

your onInit method was inside the constructor, try it in the following way

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, public authService: AuthService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#showAppinfo").click(function () {
            $("#appinfo").slideToggle();
        });
    });

}
ngOnInit() { }}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted.