# Easiest and Shortest way possible to use jQuery in Angular 2/4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

[How to use jQuery with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

[How to import jQuery to Angular2 Typescrypt projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511788/how-to-import-jquery-to-angular2-typescrypt-projects)

I don't know if this is safe but will sure help you. quite

Comment: read this: https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to

Comment: there are already so many answers for the same, what you exactly want to know ? is somewhere you stuck ? post your code then

Answer (score 0):

**1st Step**

From index.html

> ***my-test-project\src\index.html***

Type jQuery cdn below `app-root` tag.

```
...
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

**2nd Step**

> ***my-test-project\src\app\test\test.component.ts***

Go to your desired components .ts script.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// this line will allow you to use jQuery
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
```

**3rd Step**

> ***my-test-project\src\app\test\test.component.ts***

Test jQuery by logging `'I<3Cats'` inside jQuery syntax `$(() => { /* content here */ })`.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(() => {
      console.log('hello there!');
    });
  }

}
```

You can also use this technique with other javscript libraries. I don't know if this is safe but will sure help you. quite

Answer (score 0):

We have two option, for using jQuery in angular2/4.

**Step 1:**

Download jQuery library into your project folder and specify the path in angular/cli json withing the script module.

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

**Step 2**: or we can use the online CDN or the local path of the jQuery library in `index.html`

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
//here you can give link to it
  </head>
```