# Selecting default value in bootstrap select picker using angular 4 programmatically

Tags: angular, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker, elementref

I am using bootstrap selectpicker in my angular 4 application and I have to default value to it from my type script code.
These are the jquery methods given in this documentation https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/

I want to call the methods only using angular.
I have tried using ElementRef,
here is my code,

```
 this.elementref.nativeElement.selectpicker('val',[defaultvalues])
```

It gives me the error "selectpicker is not a function".
But logging this.elementref.nativeElement prints the "select" element as shown below.

```
<select _ngcontent-c4="" appselectpicker="" class="selectpicker ng-untouched
 ng-pristine ng-valid" data-live-search="true" formcontrolname="category" 
 multiple="" title="Any" tabindex="-98" ng-reflect-name="category">
      <option _ngcontent-c4="" data-tokens="Food">Food </option>
      <option _ngcontent-c4="" data-tokens="Coffee">Coffee</option>
      <option _ngcontent-c4="" data-tokens="Night Life">Night 
      Life</option>
      <option _ngcontent-c4="" data-tokens="Breakfast">Breakfast</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide the console.log output for this element.

Comment: I have added the console.log output of the element in the question @Myonara

Comment: bootstrap-selectpicker is a jquery plugin, so maybe you need help to [use jquery together with angular2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular).

Comment: Ya its possible if I use jquery inside angular, but I dont want to use jquery. Is thr any way I can do this using angular only.? @Myonara

Comment: I don't see a way to use a jquery plugin wihtout jquery. Perhaps another package like [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).