# Can I use .effect Jquery in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui

I want to use `$("#myId").effect("highlight", {color:"#b1b1b1"}, 3000);` for making some point prominent.

or do you have any code fit more than `.effect`in Angular 2

Please recommend me. thank you!

[For example like this in option "Highlight"](https://jqueryui.com/effect/)

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: `@angular/animations`?

Comment: I think it was not my point

Comment: I think you did not describe your point.

Comment: sorry I need for option "Highlight" in https://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

Comment: I can use Jquery except .effect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://angular.io/guide/animations section **Automatic property calculation**. Don't mix jQuery and Angular.

```
animations: [
  trigger('shrinkOut', [
    state('in', style({height: '*'})),
    transition('* => void', [
      style({height: '*'}),
      animate(250, style({height: 0}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [@shrinkOut]="hero.state"
      (click)="hero.toggleState()">
    {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```