# edit or add features to a minified angular app

Tags: jquery, angular, controller, minify, using-directives

I’d like to know if there is some ways to tweak an existing-already-minified-55000-lines-code ?

I work on an app and I want to add some extra stuff:
By adding new controller ? Or new directives? On the same js file or separate new js file ?

It’s quite hard to figure out , I’m fairly new in coding world, all test I’ve done so far, failed

The alternative was running jquery, but it seems that it’s not possible to run it only after the dom is rendered ...
(Spa with multiple views)

I really need to do this modification and sources are no longer exist

I can’t wait to have your help !

Thanks for taking time to read ;)

```
<!doctype html><!--Main Page "index.html"--> 
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title class="PageName">myapplitest</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="customStyles/DialogBox.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="customStyles/button.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="source/event.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body id="ezApp" ng-controller="Ctrller" ng-class="currentPageClass">
      <div  ui-view class="height-100"></div>

      <script src="scripts/scripts.f0ae5e15.js"></script>  <!--angular 55000 LINES OF CODE ^-^ -->

   </body>
</html>




<!-- the modifications I want to do in another app' view-->

<div class="modal-content infoModal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span id='titleJobModal' >{{jobInfo.name}}</span> <!--I want to act on this after the data is binded-->
        </div>
</div>


<!-- jquery there:  <script src="source/event.js"></script>
```

for this Jq snippet, when I excute it in the google console, it works..not "on load".  -->

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    $('#titleJobModal').hover(

        function () {
            $('#titleJobModal').css('color','blue');
        }, 

        function () {
            $('#titleJobModal').css('color','red');
        }
    ); /*the real challenge is to make the text change color if particular strings are in the word I look for*/
```

Victor

Comment: Be more precise about what you would want to do (with part of codes, examples...) This kind of code is basically minified in the last step, with a webpack or something like this.

Comment: Thank you for taking time ! my post is edited .

Comment: Angular doesn't work like a classic html page, you should take a look about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular