# getting error while npm run build in my Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, typescript-typings

while running angular project and creating production build I m getting following errors.

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.   Type 'this' is not
>   assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
>       Type 'MenuService' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
>         Property 'kendoBindingTarget' is missing in type 'MenuService'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'JQuery'.   Type 'Element' is not
>   assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
>       Property 'kendoBindingTarget' is missing in type 'Element'.

package dependencies are as following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "1.6.5",
  "angular-animate": "1.6.5",
  "angular-aria": "1.6.5",
  "angular-material": "1.1.4",
  "angular-messages": "1.6.5",
  "angular-route": "1.6.5",
  "d3": "4.10.0",
  "datatables": "1.10.13",
  "is-url": "^1.2.4",
  "jquery": "2.2.4",
  "jquery-mousewheel": "3.1.13",
  "js-base64": "2.3.2",
  "lodash": "4.17.5",
  "material-colors": "^1.2.5",
  "metawidget": "4.2.0",
  "moment": "2.18.1",
  "moment-timezone": "0.5.17",
  "ol": "4.6.4",
  "snapsvg": "^0.5.1",
  "sortablejs": "1.6.0",
  "spectrum-colorpicker": "1.8.0",
  "utf8": "^2.1.2",
  "uuid": "3.1.0",
  "v-accordion": "1.6.0"}
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "1.6.5",
    "@types/d3": "4.10.0",
    "@types/dagre": "0.7.39",
    "@types/datatables.net": "1.10.5",
    "@types/gridstack": "0.0.39",
    "@types/is-url": "^1.2.28",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.11.35",
    "@types/js-base64": "2.3.0",
    "@types/kendo-ui": "2017.2.1",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "0.5.6",
    "@types/openlayers": "4.3.12",
    "@types/snapsvg": "^0.4.32",
    "@types/sortablejs": "1.3.31",
    "@types/utf8": "^2.1.6",
    "@types/uuid": "3.4.0",
    "@types/websocket": "0.0.34",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-timepicker-addon": "1.6.3",
    "kendo-ui-core": "2017.2.621",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webfonts-loader": "4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-file-changer": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: Please format correctly

Comment: Seems like an error I had the first time that I installed JQuery in my angular app in one of my first apps... Avoid using JQuery with angular, if possible. If you absolutely need it (I see "datatables" between your dependecies so I guess you need it), give a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)