# How to reference jQuery functions like datepicker inside Angular Component file?

Tags: angular, datepicker

Here is my code in Angular

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Code in **.ts** file:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
@ViewChild('reportrange') reportrange: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
  jQuery(this.reportrange.nativeElement).daterangepicker();
}
```

I keep getting  jQuery(...).daterangepicker is not a function error when I compile.

What's the right approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple and will require you to install a package, you can find instructions below:

[How to use jQuery with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/4587598)