# How to assign JSON api received data to a variable in typescript?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, angular

My title say it all, I invoke an API which in return sends the data in JSON format, which I want to assign to a variable.
here is my ajax code.
Remember: I'm using it in an Angular application

I've tried to assign it to a variable, but it didn't worked.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use arrow function in order to get correct context as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.abcVariable = data; //<====== Here

  }
});
```

**Note:** It's not good practice to use jQuery in Angular application, Angular provides http module for network things.

Comment: alright, but this code doesn't work as it is.
it shows error on $ sign
Member 'summary' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular for jQuery with Angular