# Property 'printThis' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I wanted to use jQuery's property  `printThis()`  to print my view in angular 

But it is giving me this **error**.

> Property 'printThis' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

Comment: Asking Question without the code snippet in question is not a good practice. You need to include the code that does not work as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then Edit your question and improve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

Comment: can you share how did you import jqery and printThis  in your code?

Answer (score 0):

For class , use the bellow code ,

```
$(".demo").printThis();
```

For Id , use the below code ,

```
$('#demo-one, #demo-two, #demo-three').printThis({
  importCSS: false, // option
  header: "<h1>Look at all of my Demo's!</h1>" //option
});
```

For more information . Visit [this document](https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/#nada)

Comment: i used the class one. and now it removed the error but it brought another one. when i click the button now it is saying 
ERROR TypeError: $(...).printThis is not a function

Comment: Use the options with it .May it solves the problem . Or else provide your code so it make simpler for us to understand where the problem actually lies . @user10762713

Comment: `print() {
    $(".modal1").printThis();
  }`
here is my method

Comment: Use the `Id` if you are comfortable with it . 
$("#anyId").click(function() {
    $("#modalId").printThis({
        debug: true
    });
});
You can do it like this  .For  more information about it . Visit this link : http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/Tx4Uv/12

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama -sir i got $(...).printThis is not a function can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: Did you imported jquery?