# How to make full screen menu angular 6

Tags: jquery, css, angular, angular-material

I need to add full-screen menu in my project and I found a demo on https://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/yYrXRG. I copied the code from `codepen` and pasted in my project but it is not working. How to convert JQuery to Angular 6?

I solved the issue but not able to delete this question

Answer (score 3):

It's doable to include jQuery in an Angular project (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular) and demonstrated [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular-when-you-absolutely-have-to-42c8b6a37ff9)) but you really shouldn't need jQuery when creating an Angular app. It introduces a lot of unnecessary bloat and risk of bugs for a framework that provides libraries to do this sort of thing already (see [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations)).

In most cases, unless it's a legacy app and jQuery is already being used, it's best to avoid using jQuery since ES6 and newer provides everything you need.