# Integrate jQuery control in angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, angular8, syncfusion

We are trying to integrate a jQuery version of a control in an Angular 8 application. I tried initializing the component in `ngAfterViewInit()` but I'm getting an error.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  jq("#PivotGrid").ejPivotGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: this.data,
      rows: [{
        name: 'departmentName',
        caption: 'Department',
        showSubTotals: false
      }, {
        name: 'className',
        caption: 'Class',
        showSubTotals: false
      }, {
        name: 'metricName',
        caption: 'Metric'
      }],
      columns: [{
        name: 'year',
        caption: 'Year'
      }, {
        name: 'quarterDescription',
        caption: 'Quarter'
      }, {
        name: 'monthDescription',
        caption: 'Month'
      }, {
        name: 'weekDescription',
        caption: 'Week'
      }, {
        name: 'channel',
        caption: 'Channel'
      }, ],
      values: [{
        name: 'metricValue',
        caption: 'Metric Value'
      }, ]
    }
  });
}
```

Error is

**TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).ejPivotGrid is not a function**

**Script section in angular.json**

```
     "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/assets/scripts/ej.js"
        ]
```

Comment: And the error is...? Also, remove the trailing commas in your arrays. They will cause issues in IE

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan error i am getting is 
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).ejPivotGrid is not a function

but i included the library, tried including in index.html as cdn and also tried downloading script and included in angular.json . Both didn't work.

Comment: The problem might be somewhere in your `angular.json`.

Comment: Have you declared `ejPivotrGrid` in a typings file? Something like this - `interface JQuery{ejPivotGrid(options: any): JQuery;}`

Comment: Hi @Sam can u please elaborate. Is it something like i have to create *.d.ts file and declare a interface in it?

Comment: Hey, yeah that's correct otherwise typescript won't know what ejPivotGrid() is and its relationship to jQuery. There is a good example of it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular

Comment: @DileepGaganR: If you are looking for the typings use the command `npm install @types/ej.web.all --save-dev` to install the required type definitions.

Comment: @DileepGaganR: Also, you can use the `jquery` typings by running the command `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

Comment: Hi @Karthick  I tried mentioned steps still getting same error. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Sam I tried mentioned steps still getting same error. any help is much appreciated

Comment: Where is ejPivotTable from? How have you added it to your project?

Comment: @Sam I tried in both the ways downloading the entire script and also using cdn. No luck in both cases

Comment: @DileepGaganR: Can you please share your simple sample in github.? It would help to get the insight and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, we have prepared a sample in Angular 8 for your reference. Kindly check the below sample and documentation link.

Sample Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/sample1592888818

Documentation Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/pivotgrid/getting-started#relational

We hope the above sample meets your requirement. If still the problem exists, kindly reproduce the issue in the provided sample and revert us. This would be helpful for us to proceed further.