# Angular 9 does not recognise HTML <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

My dashboard.component.html

```
     <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">Collapse</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click',function(){
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

This compiles perfectly along with other code inside the dashboard.component.html file, but after ng serve. My application does not execute the Collapse button when clicked.

If I run the file separately as index.html with its style.css outside Angular Framework, it tends to work fine. The issue exists with bootstrap libraries not being executed by Angular or something related.

I have rest of the full functional code in stackblitz for reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboardissue

Comment: First, If you want to load external scripts, it should be in index.html. Second for using jquery, please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular

Comment: just copying the script tags to index.html got the job done! Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do it that way. You can easily toggle Sidebar with just Angular and you don't have to mix jQuery in it.

app.component.html

```
<button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse"(click)="toggleSidebar()" class="btn btn-info">Collapse</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  collapsed: boolean = false;

  toggleSidebar(): void {
    this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
  }
}
```

Updated your version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dashboardissue-zxiuvt

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's lot of code to do it, as dallows replied if you want simplify more use a arrow function in just 1 line.

```
toggleSidebar = () => this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
```