# How to include jquery plugin in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular5

I tried to inlude jquery plugin into angular 2 for gallery lightbox but not working.How to resolve this issue.

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jquery-integration-utimql?file=.angular-cli.json

angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "styles": ["styles.css"],
    "scripts": [ 
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "./app/js/fliplightbox.min.js"
      ]
  }]
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit()
{
    $(document).ready(() => {
          $('#image').flipLightBox();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jQuery with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular)

Comment: @Rafa: Getting error: jQuery.Deferred exception: jquery_1.default(...).flipLightBox is not a function