# How to make d3-lasso working on d3 forcedirected network?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3.js-lasso

I've tried several different changes to make my lasso work, but I keep getting the following error.

[image]

Here's my `lasso` implementation as done by the author.

```
 var lasso = d3.lasso()
      .closePathSelect(true)
      .closePathDistance(100)
      .items(node)
      .targetArea(this.svg)
      .on("start", lasso_start)
      .on("draw", lasso_draw)
      .on("end", lasso_end);

    //self.svg.call(lasso);


    // Lasso functions
    var lasso_start = function () {
      lasso.items()
        .attr("r", 8) // reset size
        .classed("not_possible", true)
        .classed("selected", false);
    };

    var lasso_draw = function () {

      // Style the possible dots
      lasso.possibleItems()
        .classed("not_possible", false)
        .classed("possible", true);

      // Style the not possible dot
      lasso.notPossibleItems()
        .classed("not_possible", true)
        .classed("possible", false);
    };

    var lasso_end = function () {
      // Reset the color of all dots
      lasso.items()
        .classed("not_possible", false)
        .classed("possible", false);

      // Style the selected dots
      lasso.selectedItems()
        .classed("selected", true)
        .attr("r", 10);

      // Reset the style of the not selected dots
      lasso.notSelectedItems()
        .attr("r", 8);

    };

    this.svg.call(lasso);
```

But whenever I run this, I always get the above error and I have no clue why.

I used the minified `d3-lasso` from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/a85800be6d89c76c1ca98493ae777572)

[StackBlitz](https://angular-ivy-y1bxvp.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Could you please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cju7wb ? This link will help you out. @Kuni.

Comment: @Muthupriya, I checked out the link. I see there are several errors and didn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using variables before they are declared. Change the order so that variables (**Lasso functions**) are declared before use and it should be fine.

```js
// Lasso functions
var lasso_start = function() {
  lasso.items()
    .attr("r", 8) // reset size
    .classed("not_possible", true)
    .classed("selected", false);
};

var lasso_draw = function() {

  // Style the possible dots
  lasso.possibleItems()
    .classed("not_possible", false)
    .classed("possible", true);

  // Style the not possible dot
  lasso.notPossibleItems()
    .classed("not_possible", true)
    .classed("possible", false);
};

var lasso_end = function() {
  // Reset the color of all dots
  lasso.items()
    .classed("not_possible", false)
    .classed("possible", false);

  // Style the selected dots
  lasso.selectedItems()
    .classed("selected", true)
    .attr("r", 10);

  // Reset the style of the not selected dots
  lasso.notSelectedItems()
    .attr("r", 8);
};

// initialize lasso
var lasso = d3.lasso()
  .closePathSelect(true)
  .closePathDistance(100)
  .items(node)
  .targetArea(this.svg)
  .on("start", lasso_start)
  .on("draw", lasso_draw)
  .on("end", lasso_end);

this.svg.call(lasso);
```

Comment: do you mind taking a look at my another error at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947769/why-the-value-for-r-is-negative-from-d3-hierarchy-in-circle-packing-in-d3-js? Would really appreciate any help or pointer

Comment: Sure, will take a look when I am on my machine