# What is difference if I use Jquery with Npm or I use add Jquery custom and add it to index.html?

Tags: jquery, angular, npm

There is two ways to use Jquery in angular
1)Via NPM
npm i jquery
2)Via including it in assets folder and after including it in index.html file.

Comment: first of all avoid using jquery in angular, if you wish to use it, then installing jquery package via npm is a right way. Refer to my answer on how to use jquery in angular :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887559/11048793

Comment: I wanted to know that is there any performance changes if I use it via index.html instead of NPM package?

Comment: no there aren't, try to import styles, scripts in angular json.