# Handle outside click bootstrap modal in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

As mentioned in [bootstrap modal docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) we can handle outside modal click with `hide.bs.modal`. Most of the examples present on the internet are with jquery. Can anyone help me to achieve this in Angular?
What I want to achieve is when a bootstrap modal is closed by clicking outside the modal. I want to call a function that will make an API call to the backend and update the data.

Like (menuOpened) and (menuClosed) in mat-menu of angular material, It would really be helpful to achieve `show.bs.modal` & `hide.bs.model` in a similar fashion for Angular?

Comment: you can use jquery in angular. I don' know for ngx-bootstrap but normal bootsrap packages has jquery as dependency why don't you import jquery in your component?

Comment: @JSmith I want to achieve this using vanilla JS or in angular way. No jquery use.

Comment: I understand your problem and I don't know how to help you but just take in account that what I'm trying to say here is that bootstrap uses Jquery angular or not

Answer (score 0):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662773/1713208)

I would try something like:

`.html`:

```
<div  #someModal></div>
```

`.ts`:

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $:JQueryStatic;
@ViewChild('someModal') el:ElementRef;
...
$(this.el.nativeElement).on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
    //update your data
  }
)
```

(not tested)

Comment: Same here want to achieve this in vanilla JS without the use of jQuery.