# How to include popper.js and bootstrap.js in angular project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, openlayers

I am using angular with openlayers and I am following the example posted below in the link:

```
        https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html
```

the aforementioned link provide the following information in order to work with the popover:

```
Things to know when using the popover plugin:
Popovers rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for popovers to work!
```

please let me know how to include

```
popper.js
```

and

```
bootstrap.js
```

so i can work with the popover function and get it working.

**image**:

[image]

Comment: popper is included with bootstrap, just installing boostrap and including the dist file from node_modules in angular.json would be fine. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/contents/#js-files

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap#readme)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `node_modules/dist/css/boostrap.min.css` in styles under the build section of angular.json file BEFORE `src/styles.css`. You can download the bootstrap from the npm package `npm install bootstrap`

In order to work with the pop ups you can add the bundle file of bootstrap `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` in the scripts under the build section of the same file.

EDIT: You have to download JQuery and add it to your scripts section as well.

Comment: please, i followed the steps you mentioned but i get the same error as shown in the attached screen shot

Comment: please, i followed the steps you mentioned but i get the same error as shown in the attached screen shot

Comment: Although, it's not recommended. I am using jQuery for the pop ups functionality of bootstrap components. You can install jQuery using `npm install jquery` and add it by using `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` to the scripts section under the build of angular.json file alongwith adding `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`.

Comment: i downloaded it using npm install jquery

Comment: Add `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` in your scripts of build in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

for external JavaScript or any file that you want to implement on angular.
you have to set path for that files on angular.json file

**angular.json**

[image]

for angular older version need set path on
**.angular.cli.json**

**Note** :- after changes on angular.json file, you have to recompile or restart project.

you can import files into **index.html** file.
[image]

Comment: please, should just include the name of the .js file or i have to download it and save it in a specific file and then refer to the path of the file

Comment: you can also declare on index.html file. let me update answer

Comment: @user2121 do npm install and then add the required file from **dist** folder inside **node_modules** to **angular.json**. This way you could do npm update and dont have to update script path manually if you need change version.

Answer (score 0):

**There are some step that you have to follow.**

```
-1. Install Jquery like npm instll jquery -save
-2. Install latest bootStrap npm install bootstrap@4.3.1 --save
-3. Install Popper js like npm install popper.js --save
```

**And then add styles and scripts into angular.json file like**
[image]

========================================================================

Comment: bootstrap styles should be above above `styles.css`, so that it doesn't override your styles.

Comment: please, i followed the steps you mentioned but i get the same error as shown in the attached screen shot

Answer (score 0):

**It's more easy to import bootstrap in the index.html file like this.**

[image]

**You can find the link here https://getbootstrap.com/**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just use npm to install :-

[propper]: > https://www.npmjs.com/package/propper

npm i propper --save

[bootstrap]: > https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap

npm i bootstrap --save

Comment: please, i followed the steps you mentioned but i get the same error as shown in the attached screen shot

Comment: are you using angular js or angular ?

Comment: You need to install jquery `npm i jquery --save` in order to use both bootstrap and propper

Comment: how should i know if it is angular or angular js??sorry i am new to this technology

Comment: angular js is 1st version which was written in vanilla js and a mvc framework where as angular which is 2+ version is written in typescript and uses component / module concept.

Comment: i am using angular

Comment: have you installed jquery or linked ??

Comment: then its must giving a error its  --> `npm i jquery --save` or you can add it by cdn in head tag