# Angular: An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module

Tags: jquery, node.js, angular, npm

I have just joined the **angular** community, and currently am working on a certain project, which has been going smoothly until I ran into a problems running jQuery, and after some research, some people suggested that I import jQuery into *polyfills.ts* as:

```js
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

window['$'] = jQuery
```

As a result, this showed some error suggesting I install @types/jquery. And after running:

```
C:\Users\Me\Apps\myProject> npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

The error/squiggly lines seem to have vanished but then it showed atleast 52 vulnerabilities.
After running:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Here seems like I have crashed everything, and every build returns a furious error as:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Me\Apps\myProject\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\index.js from 
C:\Users\Me\Apps\myProject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Me\Apps\myProject\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
See "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-pYwjGj\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I have been, since then, scurrying the web just like a spider, but I don't seem to get anything to soothe it.
Any help will be handsomely acknowledged.

**N.B:** I am using ***angular CLI ~13.1.2***

Regards.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30623825/3411606

Comment: I think the biggest issue for now is to solve the exception first.

Comment: The reason I posted article link was for you to explore other (simple) ways to add jQuery to your project. If the way in which you have implemented is giving you problem, try for other approach mentioned in article wherein you just need to add reference to angular.json file which I believe is much simpler then messing with polyfill files!

Comment: I just figured it out, it was version problems... I did npm audit fix --force again, and it upgraded, "Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.1.2, which is a breaking change"

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules folder. That will uninstall all installed packages. To reinstall them run the following command:

```
npm install
```

There is no 100% gurantee, that it will fix your problem, but it could help you by solving some of your vulnerabilities.