# Angular 13 project is not loading jquery with npm install jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have an Angular 13 project where we use jquery. We use jquery because we are importing another project that is coded using jquery.

So, I ran `npm install jquery`, and got this in my `package.json` file: `"jquery": "^3.5.1"`.

I checked the `node_modules` folder as well, and found that jquery has been downloaded.

Then I run `ng serve`.

Then I open Chrome and go to the `localhost` URL to access the application. I open Dev tools within Chrome, go into the command line, and type `$().jquery` to verify that jquery has been installed. When I do that, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jquery') at <anonymous>:1:4`

So, jquery has not been installed.

Any suggestions on how to install jquery with `npm install` in an Angular application?

**UPDATE:** When I added `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` to the "scripts" element in `angular.json`, the command `$().jquery` worked in the Dev console terminal and I was able to see the version number of jquery.

Comment: Because you install it doesn't mean it's included in your project. It just lays around on your hard drive. How do you include it in the actual project?

Comment: @cloned Good question. I'm not sure.

Comment: As per comment on your previous question: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular

Comment: @freedomn-m See my latest update, I got it to work by adding the jquery script to the `angular.json` file.

Comment: Please add as an answer, not as an edit - then you can accept your own answer and hopefully it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` to the "scripts" element in `angular.json`, the command `$().jquery` worked in the Dev console terminal and I was able to see the version number of jquery.