# Why NPM and Bower for the same project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower, package-managers

I am a beginner in front-end developement using package managers. I am reading the official tutorial of AngularJS. It explains how to install Angular with npm (which requires nodejs installation, this is somehow comprehensible). But `package.json` contains a line for `Bower`.

What I understand from official websites is that Bower and NPM are similar, so why to install both of them? why not only Bower which will allow skipping nodejs and npm?

Your usual simple explanations are invaluable. Thanks

Comment: One reason provided in the following SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18652918/624590 . "The reason many projects use both is that they use Bower for front-end packages and npm for developer tools like Yeoman, Grunt, Gulp, JSHint, CoffeeScript, etc."

Comment: You don't need both, but, if you're goign to take advantage of things like gulp or grunt to ease development and deployment, you're going to need npm. Also note that you can skip bower and just use npm.

Comment: @DRobinson, thank you for your informative feedback. Can I understand that there is a common part between the two but there are different in some other functionnalities, that they are both package managers but depending on the needs, one may choose one over another? am i right?

Comment: @KevinB. thank you very much, you answered my question to DRobinson before I send it.