# ASP.NET Core - Bower files in Git

Tags: asp.net, .net, git, bower

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0.1. My question is - should I push to Git all files that can be downloaded automatically by Bower?

[image: bower.json in Visual Studio]

like `bootstrap/js/src` or `bootstrap/scss`?

I mean, we usually don't push to Git whole packages referenced by NuGet, right? We are only pushing some config file with their "URIs", so that anyone can download the packages on their own, automatically when they build the project.
Is it different with Bower? Shouldn't we push to Git only changes made to `bower.json` file?

I've just started the project and GitHub shows me language statistics
like this:

[image: GitHub language statistics]

And so far I've written like 2 simple functions, not the entire Bootstrap or jQuery :)

Comment: If you're just starting out, don't use bower. Plain npm (and possibly a bundler like webpack if you find you need it) should suffice.

Comment: Why would you say, that npm is enough? From what [I've heard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm) those are two different tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unnecessary to upload those files. As [documentation says](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html)
Bower packages are installed using `Bower install` command, so everyone who clones you repository can install them himself.