# Bower versus npm - I need npm to install bower

Tags: npm, bower

I'm looking to properly set up a small demo in my git repo for public demo.
I've used both bower and npm before, though they weren't my decision.

My codebase is front-end only, so after doing a little reading, I thought bower would make more sense than npm.

Turns out I *need* npm *just to install* bower. How is this making things simpler for me at all?

Comment: Maybe this can help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899

Comment: I read that before posting  - in fact, **that post** was one of the reasons that caused to pick bower over npm in the first place.

But if npm is needed to install bower, then there really isn't any such thing as a "choice between them", is there?