# Angular-cli seed project comes with no bower, grunt, gulp how does it manage all dependencies?

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp, bower, angular-cli

Can we manage dependencies (js/css), minify, build, serve, watch ... only with node and nmp. If so how it works and why people use grunt, gulp, bower with npm ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically on what i understand (angular-cli is very recent) it hide the webpack .. in reality it use it behind the scene ... i prefer to use the stack made by myself with Webpack and npm .. but now they've just released a new feature the `AOT compiler`.

```
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html
```

In reallity it is possible to be done also with webpack .. but you need some changes of your code :

```
https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-aot-webpack
```

Angular-cli is taken (as idea) from Ember-cli .. it help you to manage and create (scaffold) your app....

I think (but it's my idea) I'll continue without it and I'll try to implement new features (as AOT) by myself cause i want to know what happen behind the scene and know everything of my stack.... but it's my personal idea

Hope it help you ..

Answer (score 0):

> Can we manage dependencies (js/css), minify, build, serve, watch ... only with node and npm.

- the "pm" in "npm" stands for "package-manager" so, of course you can use it as your main package manager.
- You can define your own [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in the `package.json` file and they'll get run when you enter arbitrary command in the console (`npm run {script-name}`). It can - in some way - replace grunt, gulp and other task-runners.

> why people use grunt, gulp, bower with npm ?

Good question, in fact it's like using a framework, when using gulp, grunt, etc, you have a single API, and you can easily find ready-made tools that fit your needs and save your time instead of writing your own script every time.

Using these tools also allow to use a unified API to run all your tasks and avoid you messing with several scripts, and question such as "how should I pass arguments to this script ?" "what is the command to run this ?" etc.

For bower vs npm there is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm)