# Why did Bower install to raw/bower_components/?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower

I've just installed Bower for the first time:

`npm install -g bower`

I created a new directory, moved into it and used `npm init` (for Gulp, which I'm about to install) and then told Bower to install Bootstrap from inside the directory:

`bower install bootstrap`

According to the documentation it should install packages to `bower_components/` but instead they got placed into `raw/bower_components/`. Why?

I'm new to Bower and am wondering if I've done something wrong? And also if I'm safe to move the `bower_components/` directory?

Comment: Have you checked bower.json settings? or .bowerrc?

Comment: There is no bower.json in the directory, I didn't use `bower init`.

Comment: Seems like I'm a bit late to the Bower party. npm and Browserify seem to be where it's at now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31219726/199700

Comment: What directory is specified under .bowerrc (if any)?

Comment: Its true npm is better way to go if that option is available to you.

Comment: Uinstalled! I'll stick with npm. Would still like to know what happened, though.