# Difference between "cant find variable" vs "is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error when loading a 3rd party script on a website that I can't reproduce.

The error is:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable x

How/why is this different than "x is not defined"?

Comment: @Steven It's the same error; some libraries catch the error and re-throw it with that message.

Comment: `x is not defined`, `x is not declared`, `x is not in scope`, `can't find variable x` are usually all just variations of the same error, their messages differing because of different browsers or browser versions.

Comment: @Bergi - Message came in on Safari 13.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.15

Comment: @Steven disagree back. We are no psychics

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641899/what-is-the-difference-between-bower-and-npm?rq=1 

How is this question any different? No code, feels like a discussion post...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Can't find variable" is a Safari message, unlike other browsers.

[Safari JS message - Citation](https://books.google.com/books?id=7pTviyp3SZYC&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=safari%20%22Can%27t%20find%20variable%22%20message%20js%20instead%20of%20%22is%20not%20defined%22&source=bl&ots=0dprSiH2KG&sig=ACfU3U24ozmyk-OFQ1SdONrVjqTI_1Tjdw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjukKmxhOjlAhWRqZ4KHTIVC5oQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=safari%20%22Can't%20find%20variable%22%20message%20js%20instead%20of%20%22is%20not%20defined%22&f=false)

[image]

Thanks all, I'll take the points.