# Set up project files

Tags: jquery, html, css, file, installation

I've done a bit of research just recently and am learning the command line, which has included node and bowser. From the information I've gathered so far, I think you can set up project files. Or maybe I'm wrong. I always set up the same folder/file structure for a project, e.g.:

```
index.html
/js
    jquery.latestversion.js
    custom.js
/images
/css
    styles.css
    bootstrap.css
```

Now this is where I'm not too sure. I want a way to set up this folder structure, create the files (with predefined snippets inside some) and also download the latest versions of jquery and bootstrap (with specific options, normally only just the grid).

Are there any specific programs/scripts I should be using to do this?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Are you looking for a command line tool to setup you project?

Comment: Hey there, sorry if I didn't explain myself enough. Yes and no. I'm also asking which you guys would suggest is the best. The command line or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman is what you are looking for. It allows you to create generators to initialize your projects structure. You can develop your own generator to fit your directories structure.

Check it out : http://yeoman.io/

Comment: How could I forget Yeomon! That's definitely a more feature rich tool.

Comment: Here's a relevant discussion you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092345/javascript-dependency-management-npm-vs-bower-vs-volo